# Regarding turtle simulator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
i am done with installing and making turtle sim package,but i am geting no idea,how to move further,can any body help me.How this turtle sim can be helpfull in learning things about robotics.?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34792/regarding-turtle-simulator/) by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Link given by @Kruse certainly is the starting to understand ros. Turtlesim is just to get you started on the various things that ROS has been built on which makes your life easier when you work on your projects. Various concepts that you may have to familiar are stacks, packages, topics, publishers, subscribers, parameters, services and responses. So you may test your understanding with turtlesim where its much easier to visualize whats happening. So please go through all the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) before you jump on to real projects.

Hope it helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros tutorials use turtlesim:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1